# How to unmarshal this nested JSON into go objects?

Tags: json, go

I have a JSON object similar to this one:

```
{
"prices": {
    "7fb832f4-8041-4fe7-95e4-6453aeeafc93": {
        "diesel": 1.234,
        "e10": 1.234,
        "e5": 1.234,
        "status": "open"
    },
    "92f703e8-0b3c-46da-9948-25cb1a6a1514": {
        "diesel": 1.234,
        "e10": 1.234,
        "e5": 1.234,
        "status": "open"
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to unmarshal this into an GO object without losing the unique ID field of each sub-item which is important information for me.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a `map` with string keys to preserve the unique IDs of each sub-price:

```
type Object struct {
    Prices map[string]*Price `json:"prices"`
}

type Price struct {
    Diesel float32 `json:"diesel"`
    E10    float32 `json:"e10"`
    E5     float32 `json:"e5"`
    Status string  `json:"status"`
}
```

Then, for example, you could loop over the unmarshaled object:

```
for id, price := range o.Prices {
    fmt.Printf("%s %v\n", id, price)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/aPhvGdtFC_

Comment: Thank you so much. That helped me allot!

Answer (score 2):

Use a map:

```
 type Station struct {
    Diesel float64
    E10 float64
    E15 float64
    Status string
 }

 type Data struct {
     Prices map[string]*Station
 }
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/z4-jkO8jPl)

Comment: Add json tags, because there is no matching between the json keys and the fields of your structs.

Comment: @T.Claverie The field tags are not required. See https://play.golang.org/p/z4-jkO8jPl

Comment: I didn't know that, I thought it was case sensitive. Thanks !